# Remove an element whilst enter animation is still running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have an animation which runs on any new item to a grid. Lets say this animation takes 5 seconds to run. Currently, if I try removing that element within the 5 seconds (so whilst the enter animation is still running), the item remains in the list until the enter animation finishes.

Looking at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#getting-started), it says that this is by design:

> You'll notice that when you try to remove an item
>   ReactCSSTransitionGroup keeps it in the DOM. If you're using an
>   unminified build of React with add-ons you'll see a warning that React
>   was expecting an animation or transition to occur. That's because
>   ReactCSSTransitionGroup keeps your DOM elements on the page until the
>   animation completes.

It ways that you need to add the following (updated to the relevant class names obviously) and it should work for the case described above:

```
.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

I'm not finding this to be the case, even though I have the described `leave` classes, I'm finding that it is still waiting for the original enter animation to finish, is this behavior correct, how do I fix this?

Here is a video showing the quirk in question - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oKerWlLZIE

If it makes a difference here is my classes:

```
.request-summary-item-holder-enter {
    background-color: #F8F5EC;
    transition: background-color 5s ease-in;
}
.request-summary-item-holder-enter.request-summary-item-holder-enter-active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.request-summary-item-holder-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.05s ease-in;
}
.request-summary-item-holder-leave.request-summary-item-holder-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
}
```

**Update:**
Source code references:

- Setting the state - https://github.com/avanderhoorn/Glimpse.Client.Prototype/blob/master/src/request/components/request-summary-view.jsx#L33
- Usage of transition group and setting keys - https://github.com/avanderhoorn/Glimpse.Client.Prototype/blob/master/src/request/components/request-summary-list-view.jsx

Comment: Quick questions: 1) Is the css transition group already mounted? 2) Are you sure that the transition group has the correct animation name? 3) does each element in the transition group have a `key` prop? These are things i ran into when setting mine up. Can you post some code showing the usage of the group?

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I've posted links to the code which should help. Let me know what you think or if you spot anything.